# calculate lunar illumination using the lunar package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate lunar illumination (%) using the `lunar` package in R for different date/time stamps. But I don't understand how to account for differences in time zone.

The "shift" argument  represents 'the number of hours by which to shift the calculation of lunar phase. By default lunar phase is calculated at 12 noon UT'. But i want to calculate values based on US/Eastern time zone. Is it correct to use the 'shift' argument for this? If it is, how would the specification of this argument deal with daylight savings?

Below my dummy df for which I'd like to calculate lunar illumination.

```
  Datetime
1 2014-01-15 14:12:46
2 2014-01-15 17:12:46
3 2014-01-15 20:12:46
4 2014-01-15 23:12:46
5 2014-01-16 02:12:46
6 2014-01-16 05:12:46
```

Code for calculating values

```
data.frame(lunar.illumination(df$Datetime, shift = 0))
```

EDIT: data added

```
df <- structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1389813166, 1389823966, 
1389834766, 1389845566, 1389856366, 1389867166), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "US/Eastern")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Can you upload data with `dput(df)`?

Comment: @Bloxx Edited my OP to include data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation notes that lunar.illumination() expects Date types, not Datetime types, and that the calculation is made in respect of 12 noon UTC. The shift is in hours.

```
> lunar.illumination(as.Date("2014-01-15"), shift = 0) == lunar.illumination(as.Date("2014-01-16"), shift = -24)
[1] TRUE
```

If you're using a time zone other than UTC, you have to calculate the shift yourself. By way of illustration, if you want the illumination at 5 AM EST, since 5 AM EST is 10 AM UTC, you'd have to shift by -2 to get the illumination you want.

The safest thing to do is to convert everything to UTC and then calculate the shifts for the resulting days. Doing this should take care of mixed time zones in your data, including EST and EDT.

In your case, something like the following should work:

```
> attr(df$Datetime, "tzone") <- "UTC"
> myshift <- as.numeric(format(df$Datetime, "%H")) - 12
[1]   7  10 -11  -8  -5  -2
> lunar.illumination(df$Datetime, shift = myshift)
[1] 0.9984888 0.9993455 0.9998490 0.9999990 0.9997953 0.9992381
```